# iPhone UIAlertView UIActionSheet tableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I have a table view. When the user clicks any cell of the tableView I want to display both UIAlertView and UIActionSheet at the same time. The AlertView should be displayed above the ActionSheet. And if the user clicks the "Cancel" button in AlertView, both the UIActionSheet and the UIAlertView should disappear at the same time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:-

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheetTitleFontStyle = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"     destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"Hello" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[actionSheetTitleFontStyle addSubview:alert];
[alert show];
```

It may help you.Thanks :)